# Change VS Code scroll step size in notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Vs Code editor jumps too many lines per mouse scroll step in a notebook

I am using Mac OS

This is so basic, that I have to be missing something simple.

Answer (score -1):

In VSCode there is a setting named `editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity`. Try setting this one to a lower value.

Comment: I tried this, and it does not work in my Jupyter notebook